# Unable to view Admin Catalog after data migration in magento 2

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, admin, database, magento2-migration-tool

Magento 2 install and migrated data from Magento 1.9.0.2 store. When I attempt to navigate to the `Admin > Products > Catalog` I get the following error message:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1103 Incorrect table name '', query was:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT main_table.attribute_id) FROM `eav_attribute` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `eav_entity_type` AS `entity_type` ON main_table.entity_type_id = entity_type.entity_type_id
 INNER JOIN `eav_entity_attribute` ON main_table.attribute_id = eav_entity_attribute.attribute_id
 INNER JOIN `` AS `additional_table` ON main_table.attribute_id = additional_table.attribute_id WHERE (`entity_type_code` = 'catalog_product') AND (`additional_table`.`is_used_in_grid` = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is already an issue on GitHub for this: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2809

The current fix would be to

1. Go to table **eav_entity_type**
2. Set field **additional_attribute_table** to **catalog_eav_attribute** where **entity_type_code** = catalog_category or catalog_product

(sorry for my pseudo SQL)